# add line to all xAxis and yAxis

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I need help with an question about how to draw a lane at every value of xAxis and yAxis.

Now I have this result:
[image: Actual]

And I need a result like this:
[image: result needed]

I think its something like :

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

but im not sure...
If someone have a idea.. just tell me.

Really thanks to all the response

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}


.axis path {
    fill: #E0E0E0;
    stroke: #bbb;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
    fill: #000;
}

.axis line {    
    stroke-width: 1;
}

.axis .axis-label {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.line {
    stroke-width: 2;
}

.y.axis line, .y.axis path {
    fill: none;
   stroke: gray;
   shape-rendering: crispEdges;
   stroke-width: 1;
}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" name="0" value="amaga"  onclick="amagar(this.name);"/>
        <input type="button" name="1" value="amaga"  onclick="amagar(this.name);"/>
        <input type="button" name="2" value="amaga"  onclick="amagar(this.name);"/>
        <input type="button" name="3" value="amaga"  onclick="amagar(this.name);"/>

        <input type="button" name="4" value="amaga"  onclick="amagalinea(this.name);"/>
        <input type="button" name="5" value="amaga"  onclick="amagalinea(this.name);"/>
    <script>
    var data =  [
    //VERD
    [{'x':15000,'y':0}, {'x':15000,'y':130},{'x':40000,'y':130},{'x':40000,'y':0},
    {'x':60000,'y':0},{'x':60000,'y':130},{'x':70000,'y':130},{'x':70000,'y':0},],

    // GRIS PARADA
    [{'x':40000,'y':0}, {'x':40000,'y':130}, {'x':60000,'y':130},{'x':60000,'y':0}],

    //TARONJA TRABAJO
    [{'x':16000,'y':40},{'x':16000,'y':80}, {'x':37000,'y':80}, {'x':37000,'y':40}],

    //BLAU RALENTI
    [{'x':17000,'y':0},{'x':17000,'y':40},{'x':35000,'y':40},{'x':35000,'y':0} ],

    //LINEA VELOCITAT
   [{'x':10000,'y':0},{'x':12000,'y':80}, {'x':15000,'y':70}, {'x':17000,'y':80},{'x':19000,'y':100},
     {'x':20000,'y':55}, {'x':27000,'y':85}, {'x':33000,'y':65}, {'x':37000,'y':25}, {'x':40000,'y':65}, {'x':45000,'y':77},
     {'x':50000,'y':47}, {'x':55000,'y':88}, {'x':59000,'y':25}, {'x':66000,'y':0}],

     //LINEA TEMPERATURA
  [{'x':10000,'y':0},{'x':12000,'y':20}, {'x':15000,'y':15}, {'x':17000,'y':18},{'x':19000,'y':17},
     {'x':20000,'y':15}, {'x':27000,'y':19}, {'x':33000,'y':12}, {'x':37000,'y':21}, {'x':40000,'y':23}, {'x':45000,'y':15},
     {'x':50000,'y':18}, {'x':55000,'y':19}, {'x':59000,'y':21}, {'x':66000,'y':20}]
];

var colors = [
    '#B4EEB4',
    'gray',
    'orange',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'pink'
]


var margin = {top: 5, right: 30, bottom: 35, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 24])
    .range([0, width]);


var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 140])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .ticks(24)
    .tickSize(-height)
    .tickPadding(10)    
    .tickSubdivide(true)    
    .orient("bottom")

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(5)
    .tickPadding(10)
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickSubdivide(true)    
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")   
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "axis-label")
    .attr("y", height+35)
    .attr("x", width/2-15)
    .text('Horas'); 



svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "axis-label")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 10)
    .attr("x", -height/2-20)
    .text('Velocidad KM/H');    

svg.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")  
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x/3600); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });     

svg.selectAll('.line')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .attr('fill', function(d,i){
         return i < 4 ? colors[i % colors.length] : 'none';
    })
    .attr("d", line);       


svg.selectAll('.line')
    .attr('stroke', function(d,i){ 
         return i >= 4 ? colors[i % colors.length] : 'none';
    });


function amagar(a){
     if(d3.select(svg.selectAll('.line')[0][a]).attr("fill") != "none"){
      d3.select(svg.selectAll('.line')[0][a]).attr("fill", "none");

        }
    else 
      d3.select(svg.selectAll('.line')[0][a]).attr("fill", colors[a % colors.length]);
}

function amagalinea(a){

    if(d3.select(svg.selectAll('.line')[0][a]).attr("stroke") != "none")
        d3.select(svg.selectAll('.line')[0][a]).attr("stroke", "none");
    else
    d3.select(svg.selectAll('.line')[0][a]).attr("stroke", colors[a % colors.length]);  
}

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);


    </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check out the d3 documentation. What you want are "ticks"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a second set of axis functions for the ticks and the other for the grid.  https://jsfiddle.net/ermineia/ah2bv6t5/

```
var xGrid = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .ticks(24)
    .tickSize(-height)
    .tickPadding(10)    
    .tickSubdivide(true)    
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat('');
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .ticks(24)
    .tickSize(5)
    .tickPadding(10)    
    .tickSubdivide(true)    
    .orient("bottom");

var yGrid = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(5)
    .tickPadding(10)
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickSubdivide(true)    
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat('');
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(5)
    .tickPadding(10)
    .tickSize(5)
    .tickSubdivide(true)    
    .orient("left");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")   
    .call(xGrid);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")   
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yGrid);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```